Keras tokenizer not appearing in import
I'm trying to generate captions using a model I trained (.keras) and I'm following this instructions: Link, I'm not following directly, I created and trained the model using Keras Image Captioning code example and saved using a function that GPT4 gave and it's working fine on that side.
Then on the generate captions, I tried GPT4 to give me some code examples but they don't work and I didn't understand so I did some research and found this Link, and I jumped to generate Image Captioning and on the code it says I need to open a tokenizer:
tokenizer = load(open('tokenizer.pkl', 'rb'))

after the debug it said to me (of course) that the file didn't exist, so I'm trying to create a tokenizer.pkl. And I can't create because I can't find the keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
Trying to import the Tokenizer I realized that it can be on 2 directories, the from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer or from keras.legacy.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer, and I have neither of them, my tensorflow version is: 2.17.0-dev20240410.
I've tried looking at the source code of Tokenizer and implement the Tokenizer function in my code but I doing that I can't found the API export:
from keras.api_export import keras_export

Thanks in advance.

I'm not an expert but it seems that it might be part of the Keras NLP library https://keras.io/keras_nlp/ did you install it ? And try from keras_nlp.tokenizers import Tokenizer ?

Yes,"pip install --upgrade keras.nlp" it says "Requirement already satisfied".

So I've found the problem but not the solution, the problem is the version, on Keras3 this directory is not available, I'm trying to found the alternative but all that I can find is to downgrade my version

Are you able to import this tokenizer for example ? https://keras.io/api/keras_nlp/tokenizers/word_piece_tokenizer/

What do you mean by import?

I can't import kerasnlp or keras-nlp

What if you write from keras_nlp.tokenizers import WordPieceTokenizer ? (Notice the underscore)

All old documentation (most of all documentation nowadays) says to import from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer, but keras 3 integrated the tokenizer in the textvetorization.
So if you use the code example you will see that you import from keras.layers import TextVectorization, that is mostly what tokenizer does, in fact, tokenizer is a class IN TextVectorization.
So to import Tokenizer you need to import TextVectorization from keras.layers and import from TextVectorization Tokenizer, like this:
from keras.layers import TextVectorization; import tokenizer

that is for Keras 3.
If you want to use
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

You can downgrade the version your using to Keras 2

I faced the same issue,
Initially keras was a independent library, later on it was integrated with tensorflow.
It is highly recommended to import the classes from tensorflow.keras
not directly from keras.
Since tensorflow 2.x is tightly integrated with keras
but with keras alone, there is always a issue of different version , setup and all.
So import Tokenizer using this way -
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
